# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of undefined

Tags: javascript, dom

can't figure out where is the error in this code. Chrome debug console keep saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of undefined" at line 31!

```
jewel.dom = (function() {

    var $ = Sizzle;

    function hasClass(el, clsName){

        var regex = new RegExp("(^|\\s) + clsName + (\\s|$)");
        return regex.test(el.className);
    }

    function addClass(el, clsName) {

        if (!hasClass(el,clsName)) {
            el.className += ""+ clsName;
        }
    }

    function removeClass (el, clsName) {

        var regex = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + clsName + "(\\s|$)");
        el.className = el.className.replace(regex, " ");
    }

    function bind(element, event, handler) {

        if (typeof element == "string") {
            element = $(element)[0];
        }

        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false)
}

    return {
        $:$,
        hasClass : hasClass,
        addClass : addClass,
        removeClass : removeClass,
        bind : bind
    };
;}) ();
```

Comment: `element` does not exist. Please post the code which calls `bind()` and the code which definites `element`.

Comment: Found it! It was in another script the problem. I've used google chrome developer console e tracked the callback in the right script :D

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this is caused by Evernote Clipper extension script. You will find "Evernote" in comment when you click to that script who throws out the error.

Comment: In my case I have this error in another script. Switching it off solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the case that your `bind` invocation ends up with an `undefined` `element`? (e.g. you pass a selector that does not match any of the elements in your DOM)

Answer (score 0):

some browsers don't know what "addEventListener" is. Try this:

```
Element.prototype.setEvent = function(eventName, handler)
{
    if(document.addEventListener)
    {
        this.addEventListener(eventName, handler);
    }
    else
    {
        if(document.attachEvent)
        {
            this.attachEvent("on" + eventName, handler);
        }
    }
}
element.setEvent(eventName, handler);
```

The same goes for removeEventListener.

Also, try to replace

```
 element = $(element)[0];
```

with

```
 element = $("#" + element);
```

provided that string contains the id of the element, or

```
 element = $("." + element)[0];
```

if the string contains the className of the element.

Comment: This browser does know: "TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' `of undefined`" at line 31!"

Comment: It's not a browser problem, maybe Pavlov is right...who knows where in the various script is the problem...